# google xml sitemap won't work on directory install

Tags: directory, installation, google-xml-sitemaps

I have installed wordpress in directory above the root called "wp". I'm having issues with the google xml sitemap generator. I cannot rebuild the xml code and write it the sitemap.xml file. I have been on the phone with my hosting company and they assure me the file does have full control for its file permissions.

Does anyone have any advice for this?

Comment: There are that many out there. Please link the one you're using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hate to self promote BUT ;)

My [WordPress SEO plugin](http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/) actually fixes this by not generating a static file at all. It works in all circumstances.